# C# SOAP Service without WCF

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf, web-services, soap

I'm trying to create a SOAP web service and web client in C# ***without using the WCF tools***.  My objective is to create a client that communicates with a SOAP service that most likely is not using WCF.  *I made a proof of concept client, but at the moment I'm not really sure how to write the raw SOAP XML to send to the WCF service to test my client.*  Also, can I use WCF on the client side even if the SOAP service does not use WCF?  Thanks!

**SOAP Client:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Xml;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

namespace HttpSoapPoc.Models
{
    public class SoapClient
    {
        protected virtual WebRequest CreateRequest(ISoapMessage soapMessage)
        {
            var wr = WebRequest.Create(soapMessage.Uri);
            wr.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=utf-8";
            wr.ContentLength = soapMessage.ContentXml.Length;

            wr.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", soapMessage.SoapAction);
            wr.Credentials = soapMessage.Credentials;
            wr.Method = "POST";
            wr.GetRequestStream().Write(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(soapMessage.ContentXml), 0, soapMessage.ContentXml.Length);

            return wr;
        }

        public interface ISoapMessage
        {
            string Uri { get; }
            string ContentXml { get; }
            string SoapAction { get; }
            ICredentials Credentials { get; }
        }

        public static string CallWebService()
        {
            var _url = "https://passport.iso.com/PPWebListener/services/SOAPListenerV2";
            var _action = "https://passport.iso.com/PPWebListener/services/SOAPListenerV2?op=HelloWorld";

            XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml = CreateSoapEnvelope();
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = CreateWebRequest(_url, _action);
            InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(soapEnvelopeXml, webRequest);

            // begin async call to web request.
            IAsyncResult asyncResult = webRequest.BeginGetResponse(null, null);

            // suspend this thread until call is complete. You might want to
            // do something usefull here like update your UI.
            asyncResult.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne();

            // get the response from the completed web request.
            string soapResult;
            using (WebResponse webResponse = webRequest.EndGetResponse(asyncResult))
            {
                using (StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(webResponse.GetResponseStream()))
                {
                    soapResult = rd.ReadToEnd();
                }
                return soapResult;
            }

        }

        private static HttpWebRequest CreateWebRequest(string url, string action)
        {
            HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            webRequest.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", action);
            webRequest.ContentType = "text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\"";
            webRequest.Accept = "text/xml";
            webRequest.Method = "POST";
            return webRequest;
        }

        private static XmlDocument CreateSoapEnvelope()
        {
            XmlDocument soapEnvelop = new XmlDocument();
            String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>";
            xml += "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">";
            xml += "<soap:Body>";
            xml += "<CelsiusToFahrenheit xmlns=\"http://tempuri.org/\">";
            xml += "<Celsius>20</Celsius>";
            xml += "</CelsiusToFahrenheit>";
            xml += "</soap:Body>";
            xml += "</soap:Envelope>";
            soapEnvelop.LoadXml(xml);
            return soapEnvelop;
        }

        private static void InsertSoapEnvelopeIntoWebRequest(XmlDocument soapEnvelopeXml, HttpWebRequest webRequest)
        {
            using (Stream stream = webRequest.GetRequestStream())
            {
                soapEnvelopeXml.Save(stream);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**SOAP Service:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;
using System.ServiceModel;
using System.ServiceModel.Web;
using System.Text;
using System.ServiceModel.Activation;

namespace SoapTutorial
{
    [AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]
    public class SoapService : ISoapService
    {
        public Employee[] GetEmployees()
        {
            return new Employee[]
            {
                new Employee() { EmpNo=101, EmpName="Mahesh", DeptName="CTD" },
                new Employee() { EmpNo=102, EmpName="Akash", DeptName="HRD" }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use WCF with basicHttpBinding. This will create a SOAP service interoperable by non-WCF clients.

Comment: So all I really need for the WCF service is to modify the web.config / package.config?  [<basicHttpBinding>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731361.aspx)

Comment: Note thet basicHttpBinding is SOAP 1.1 (which is what OP appears to need).  If it was SOAP 1.2, they could use wsHttpBinding.